# Does Radikal Bikers exists for PS3?

Tags: arcade, psn

It was a very great arcade involving bikers delivering pizza.
Does it exists as a PSN download?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information I found states that it is not available and not planned. However, a little research on the PSN and you will get the true answer;)

Comment: huh (++15 huhs)

Answer (score 2):

For your region the PlayStation Store has an alphabetical list by title of all content released be it a trailer, demo, DLC, etc. For the US store I do not see anything by the name "Radikal Bikers". (Nor does a search for "radikal" return any matches.)

Your region may be different and have content not available to me.